# Slice Data in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to slice number of rows into two per group.

So for example if I have 10 rows and I want to slice it into 2 per group then both record should have same id.

Input:

```
Name 
adc
abc
Cdd
Dee
Eaa
```

Output should be two columns:

```
COUPLEID | NAME
       1   adc
       1   abc
       2   Cdd
       2   Dee
       3   Eaa
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by taking the [row_number() function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx), dividing that result by 2, and adding 1.

If you're sure of the number of records in the results, you could also use the [NTILE() function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175126.aspx), where the argument to function is the number of rows divided by 2.

Comment: I hate it when others tell you basics but that is the way it is when there is an hammer knocking to get things going!!!!. 

I can do that by using (RowNumber-1)/2 + 1 . Thank you for the direction.

Answer (score 0):

```
select row_number() over (order by NAME) / 2 + 1 as COUPLEID, NAME
from T
order by COUPLEID, NAME
```